# How to get one result with multiple data in other table

Tags: mysql, php

My problem is this.

I want to put table1 in combo box with one result with different data from table2. I hope you can get my point.. sorry.. :)

My tables:

[image]
[image]

This is my coding.

```
            $table2="SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE tid=".$tid;
            $rtable2=mysqli_query($conn, $table2) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($conn));  
                if(mysqli_num_rows($rtable2)){
                    while($rowtable2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rtable2)){     
            
                        $table1="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tid= ".$rowtable2['tid'];
                        $rtable1=mysqli_query($conn, $table1) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($conn));
                        
                        // last touch                   
                    }                   
                }
                if(mysqli_num_rows($rtable1)){
                    while($rowtable1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rtable1)){                                 
                        echo "  
                            <option value='".$rowtable1['tid']."'>".$rowtable1['name']."</option>
                        ";          
                    }                   
                }
```

Output:

[image]

I want to be like this.

[image]

Comment: Your combo box needs to display the name column and pass the corresponding tid column to your code. This maybe a programming question and not for DBA Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first line:

```
$table2="SELECT DISTINCT(tid) FROM table2";
```

But you could also put this in 1 statement:

```
$table="SELECT DISTINCT(table2.tid) as tid, table1.name as name FROM table2 LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 on table1.id=table2.tid";
$rtable=mysqli_query($conn, $table) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($conn));  
if(mysqli_num_rows($rtable)){
  while($rowtable=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rtable)){                                 
    echo "<option value='".$rowtable['tid']."'>".$rowtable['name']."</option>";
  }                   
}
```